# Connect to PostgreSQL from Oracle with only PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql, database-link

I am working on an Oracle script that needs data from PostgreSQL and will be run on a number of different servers. The connection to the data will remain the same, so I would like to connect to PostgreSQL without modifying the tnsnames.ora file or adding an ODBC connection.

I have been trying to use `CREATE DATABASE LINK`, but I'm not finding a way to connect to a driver without going through an ODBC connection:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK "LinkName"
CONNECT TO "PgSqlUserName" IDENTIFIED BY "PgSqlPassword"
USING '(DESCRIPTION=
 (ADDRESS=
 (PROTOCOL=TCP)
 (HOST=PgSqlServerName)
 (PORT=5432))
 (CONNECT_DATA=
 (SID=PgSqlDatabaseName)))';
```

Trying to run

```
SELECT * FROM "PgSqlTable"@"LinkName";
```

gives the error message:

```
ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed
12537. 00000 -  "TNS:connection closed"
*Cause:    "End of file" condition has been reached; partner has disconnected.
*Action:   None needed; this is an information message.
Error at Line: xx Column: xx
```

Is there a way to connect to a PostgreSql database from Oracle without modifying the tnsnames.ora file or setting up an ODBC connection?

Comment: Oracle's database link can only connect to another Oracle instance. Btw: there is no PL/SQL in your example

Comment: check this link could help : https://dbaspot.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/how-to-access-postgresql-from-oracle-database/